# PageView.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

How can I rebuild my PageView.builder? when I change `_type` property in `MyPage`, I want rebuild it

```
child: PageView.builder(
            controller: _controller,
            itemCount: items.length,
            allowImplicitScrolling: true,
            reverse: false,
            onPageChanged: (int position) {
              item = items[position];
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, position) => MyPage(
                  item: items[position],
                  type: _type)),
```

Comment: setState should be able to `rebuild` your widgets

Comment: When build PageView flutter preload 3 pages. When in ``MyPage`` I change ``type`` property, I want rebuild another 2 pages, because, if I change my ``type`` and swipe left, in first page ``type`` property isn't changed

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your onPageChanged part. you should do something like this.

```
child: PageView.builder(
      controller: _controller,
      itemCount: items.length,
      allowImplicitScrolling: true,
      reverse: false,
       onPageChanged: (int position) {
          setState(
             () {
            currentIndex = position;
             },
            );
           },
         itemBuilder: (context, position) => MyPage(
            item: items[position],
            type: _type)),
```